# Total I/O cost of a process

Tags: linux, io

I know that `iotop` lets me measure the disk bandwidth used by any or all processes in real time. `iotop -a` measures the accumulated disk bandwidth, which is closer to what I want.

However, when the process I run terminates, it disappears too soon in iotop for me to be able to see exactly how many I/Os the process used in total since it started. Is there a way to record the total I/O usage of a process when it ends, and perhaps have this saved to some file for further analysis?

Note that I am only looking for answers exclusive to Linux, specifically Ubuntu.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try [pidstat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pidstat). Use it like this: `pidstat -d -e command`

`pidstat` is able to report statistics for Linux tasks. The `-d` instructs `pidstat` to gather IO stats. `pidstat` will stop and print the report once the command finished.

Comment: Thanks, what's the purpose of the -e flag? Couldn't find a source online for that.

Comment: You might not need `-e`. On ArchLinux `man pidstat` states for `-e`: `Execute program with given arguments args and monitor it with pidstat. pidstat stops when program terminates.`

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to work. No matter which program I run, the report is always sent right at the beginning, before the command actually outputs anything. So of course, everything is at 0,00. What is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

`iotop` has `--batch` option, which you can use to process it non-interactively.
That would allow you to do (for example):

```
sudo iotop --batch -qqq --accumulated | fgrep --line-buffered '% dd ' | tee  ~/dd.log
```

which would provide output like:

```
19804 be/4 user  0.00 B      0.00 B  0.00 %  0.00 % dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/log.1 bs=1M count=10000
19804 be/4 user  0.00 B    755.18 M  0.00 % 30.99 % dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/log.1 bs=1M count=10000
19804 be/4 user  0.00 B   1029.48 M  0.00 % 50.96 % dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/log.1 bs=1M count=10000
```

Last line matching your `fgrep(1)` string (in this example looking for `dd` command) is your final cumulative line.

Also, the output remains in `~/dd.log` for your later parsing as needed. (you can also reverse the ordering of `tee` and `fgrep` if you want to save ALL iotop output to logfile, not just output specific to `dd` in example)

Comment: But this runs every second lets say. If my process runs for 42.6 seconds, then the last 0.6 seconds of I/O would be missed by I/O top?

Comment: @user308485 yes, that is correct. You can use `-d 0.1` for example to use even smaller polling unit than 1 second, but in the end with iotop you will always lose some small amount of I/O statistics. Also, it is possible that some process starts and ends very quickly (for example, 1/100th of the seconds) and so it might not show at all in iotop